# Thread dies at specific line for no reason

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, wcf, remote-debugging

I'm debugging remotely a WCF app hosted in Azure as an AppService. The debugging process works very well until i reach a specific line (a static method of a class that does nothing special). Now, if i press F11 to step into that method, the debugger does nothing and the thread dies. In the debug output window there are some exceptions printed and it can also be seen that one thread exited with code 0x0. The code path i am debugging is SINGLE-threaded and synchronous. Also the app uses Application Insights.

My question is: How should i start investigating this problem? Please give me a checklist to run through because i have no idea what could be the cause.

Comment: Open the "Exceptions" panel in Visual Studio (Debug -> Windows -> Exception settings), and check the box in front of "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". Run your scenario again, and Visual Studio will automatically break on the exception, letting you inspect it and understand why it was thrown

Comment: _"... the debug output window there are `some exceptions` printed...Please give me a checklist to run through "_ - 1) **list** the exceptions _here_ 2) show us the code that _"does nothing special"_

Comment: I have managed to fix it somehow. Thanks for your comments. I think it was either a faulty build or Azure killing my thread.